# Creating transitions on the navigation stack that show both source and destination views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

The native push transition shows the source view, and the transition over to the destination view seamlessly.

The modal transition shows the destination view overlaying the source view from the bottom.

I'd like a modal transition that works with the navigation controller.

So far I have this:

```
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
    anim.duration = .2;
    anim.autoreverses = NO;
    anim.removedOnCompletion = YES;

    anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:sourceViewController.view.frame.size.height];
    anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];

    [sourceViewController.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:anim
                                                                 forKey:kCATransition];

    [sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO];
```

This is in the `-perform` method in my segue subclass. The problem with this is that the navigation controller push is done almost immediately, and while the transition takes place, nothing of the source view is displayed. I want it to look as if it's overlaying.

I thought it might be possible to take a screenshot using Core Graphics and having that as a superview of the destination view, but I couldn't get it to work properly.

I also tried using one of the `UIView` animation methods like so:

```
[sourceViewController.view addSubview:destinationController.view];
    [destinationController.view setFrame:sourceViewController.view.window.frame];
    [destinationController.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, sourceViewController.view.frame.size.height)];
    [destinationController.view setAlpha:1.0];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.3
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                     animations:^{
                         [destinationController.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)];
                         [destinationController.view setAlpha:1.0];

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [destinationController.view removeFromSuperview];
                         [sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO];

                     }];
```

But again, there's an issue with this: the navigation bar isn't displayed until the view controller is actually pushed onto the navigation stack. So there's a sort of "jump" at the end of the animation when the navigation bar is suddenly displayed.

So what are my options with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by taking the route of creating an image of the source view and transitioning over that.

Also, it should be noted that the "flash" doesn't exist on ios 7 so there isn't much custom code necessary.